# how to make a list fully transparent in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm a SwiftUI beginner. I'm facing a problem to make a List as I want in a SwiftUI app !

This is my code:

```
struct Search: View {

@ObservedObject var webservice = Webservice()

@State var depart = "Gent-Sint-Pieters"

@State var destination = "Mechelen"

var body: some View {

    VStack (spacing: 20){

        Rechercher(depart: $depart , destination: $destination)       

        HStack {

                List(webservice.rides, id:\.id) { item in

                    Text("")

                }

                //.colorMultiply(Color(hue: 0.547, saturation: 0.071, brightness: 1.0))

            Spacer()
        }

        RechercheButton()
    }
}
}
```

What I want is to remove the white background of the list. Is it possible ?

Can you tell me what I need to add to this code to have a result like this (with a content between each of the gray separator lines and no background color for the list) ?

[image]

thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set clear color in init method of view

```
init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear 
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
```

So, your answer will be like below

```
struct Search: View {

@ObservedObject var webservice = Webservice()

@State var depart = "Gent-Sint-Pieters"

@State var destination = "Mechelen"

init() {
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear 
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        }

var body: some View {

    VStack (spacing: 20){

        Rechercher(depart: $depart , destination: $destination)       

        HStack {

                List(webservice.rides, id:\.id) { item in

                    Text("")

                }

                //.colorMultiply(Color(hue: 0.547, saturation: 0.071, brightness: 1.0))

            Spacer()
        }

        RechercheButton()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really useful pattern is to insert an anonymous block in the view's body. Be sure to `return` the view that follows e.g.

```swift
    var body: some View {
        let _ = {
        }()
        return Text("Cool")
    }
```

So in your case:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        let _ = {
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }()
        return List { … }
    }
```

Additional useful stuff with tables:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        let _ = {
            // Removes space between nav bar bottom and top of form's table view top
            UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
            // Remove lines between rows
            UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
            // Set list row background color to clear
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            // Set list background color to clear
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }()
        return List { … }
    }
```